# CSS: text-indent and text-align are ignored

Tags: html, css, text-align, text-indent

I guess the answer to this may be simple, but I can't figure it out on my own.

I've got the following HTML:

```
<div id="excerpt">
    <p class="chapter">Chapter One</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <div class="copyright-notice">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2014 Name. All rights reserved.</p>
    </div>
    <!--end copyright-notice-->
</div>
<!--end excerpt-->
```

and the following CSS to go with it:

```
#excerpt {
    padding:20px;
    color:#000000;
}
#excerpt p {
    line-height:1.4em;
    text-indent:45px;
    text-align:justify;
}
p.chapter {
    text-align:center;
    text-indent:0;
    font-size:16pt;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.copyright-notice {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
    border-top: 1px solid #999999;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:20px;
}
.copyright-notice p {
    display: block;
    color:#666666;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent:0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle reproduction](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/35smhzpa/1/).

As you can see I try to center the text and set the indent to 0 for the paragraph with the chapter class as well as the text within the copyright notice. But it doesn't work.
If I apply the style to the paragraph directly in the HTML file like:

```
<p style="text-align:center;text-indent:0;">text</p>
```

[JS Fiddle reproduction](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/35smhzpa/2/).

It'll work. But as soon as I try to style those paragraphs through CSS text-align and text-indent get ignored.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issue.

The selector `#excerpt p` is more specific than `p.chapter`. Therefore `text-indent:0` isn't applied. The reason it was applied when using the `style` attribute, is because inline CSS is more specific.

More specifically, (pun intended), `#excerpt p` has a specificity calculation of 101. Whereas `p.chapter` has a specificity of 11. (An id is 100 points, a class is 10, and an element is 1).

As for a solution, use either of the following to avoid the specifity conflict.

```
p {
    text-indent:45px;
}
p.chapter {
    text-indent:0;
}
```

or..

```
#excerpt p {
    text-indent:45px;
}
#excerpt p.chapter {
    text-indent:0;
}
```

<sub>(Other styling omitted from brevity.)</sub>

The latter example is probably what you should go with because you don't want all paragraph elements to be indented, just those that are a descendant of `#excerpt`. I'd avoid using `id`'s in CSS as much as possible though - save those for JS.

Comment: Have a corroborating [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/35smhzpa/). Why yes, you were a little faster than me. Goshdarnit... ;)

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks so much.